# Build Apk Error - Duplicate entry : android/support/v4/database/DatabaseUtilsCompat.class?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-support-library, android-support-design

My Gradle is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.belajarku.gamelari"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true


    }

    dexOptions {
        // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }


    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
}
```

But when I **build apk** the project say me :

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     android/support/v4/database/DatabaseUtilsCompat.class

Please help me for fix it.

Comment: Asked so many times that is hard to point good duplicate. Please, analyze your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/database/DatabaseUtilsCompat.class

You are adding twice the same class with different versions.

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'support-v4'} 
compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
```

Using `com.google.android.gms:play-services:+` you are adding all packages of play services libraries which **have a dependency** with the support-v4.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your support dependencies to the same version of compileSdkVersion. Your **compileSdkVersion** is 25, hence your support library should also be 25.

Don't use the whole package of Google Play service, choose what you need read from [Set Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). For example, if you want to use google ads, add only `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4`. You need to change your dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // only use google ads from google service.
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    ...
}
```

Then you can disable your multidex by setting `multiDexEnabled false` or commenting it and removing `compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')` from your dependencies.